# Return array keys if values are same and highest with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$arr = array(
         'English' => 70,
         'Physics' => 65,
         'Math' => 70, 
         'Chemistry' => 60,
         'Geography' => 70,
         'Biology' => 65

       );
```

See user got highest in three subjects. I want to return the keys of all the highest number in the array. So it should return here: `English, Match and Geography` because they are of same values and highest. I have tried this:

```
arsort($arr);
if(count(array_unique($arr)) === 1) {
     return array_keys($arr);

}
```

But it works if array has only two elements in it, not with multiple elements. How i can achieve returning the keys if array has same highest values in it?

**Note:** User also got same in Physics and Biology. But those number are not highest. So it should not return the keys for non-highest number even though they are of same values. The need is to return keys of the **highest and same values**.

Comment: what about chemistry ? that is the height. right ?

Comment: Sorry i updated the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
$by_score = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $score) {
    if (!isset($by_score[$score])) {
        $by_score[$score] = array();
    }
    $by_score[$score][] = $key;
}
ksort($by_score);
$highest = end($by_score);
```

Comment: Right. I didn't notice the notification about the answer being edited 16 minutes before and I commented on an old version :-)

Comment: changing the array values a little bit i got this by a `print_r` : 
`Array
(
    [65] => Array
        (
            [0] => Physics
            [1] => Biology
        )

    [70] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chemistry
            [1] => Geography
        )

    [71] => Array
        (
            [0] => English
            [1] => Math
        )

)` . I want to do another thing. I want to make new arrays with the last two key 71, 70. So take the last two keys and make new array like this. `$arr1 = array('English', 'Math');

$arr2 = array('Chemistry', 'Geography');`

Comment: @Rudi Thanks for the solution. How i can make two new arrays with the last two keys? I need it for some reasons.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you right, try to change the last line to: `$highest = array_slice($by_score, -2);` ...for the last 2 items in the array

Comment: @Rudi Thats what i asked for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to walk the array and create a new array that uses the number of points as keys and associate to each key a list of classes that have that number of points. Sort the new array by keys (points) descending, get the first value:

```
// Create a new array that contains the classes indexed by points
$reverse = array();
array_walk(
    $arr,
    // Need to pass $reverse by reference to change it in the function
    function ($value, $key) use (& $reverse) {
        if (! isset($reverse[$value])) {
            $reverse[$value] = array();
        }
        // Put all the classes having the same number of points into the same list
        $reverse[$value][] = $key;
    }
);

// Sort by keys (the number of points) descending
krsort($reverse);
// Get the first entry from the sorted array
// It is the list of classes having the biggest number of points
$output = reset($reverse);
```